# ¿Como llenar el radio button con javascript con datos de la BD?

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery, base-de-datos, jquery-ui

Necesito que al cargar la pagina el radio button quede seleccionado con el dato de la base de datos.

Comment: Porque no colocas el codigo que tienes, y de esa forma tendras respuestas mucho mas concisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que necesitas debes hacer uso del método val()

```
$("INPUT[name=nombre_del_radio]").val([valor_que_trae_tu_funcion]);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el atributo checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="xxx"  value="" checked />
```

o:

```
<input type="radio" name="xxx"  value="" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: Pero como envio el valor desde javascript para que se cargue el  radio button